# not getting the proper page through jsoup

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

I am trying to get this page with **jsoup**: http://poalimparents.bankhapoalim.co.il/

But all I get is this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>window.rbzns = {fiftyeightkb: 43200000, days_in_week : 1};</script>
  <script src="//d1a702rd0dylue.cloudfront.net/js/sugarman/v7/flat.js"></script>
  <script>rbzns.challdomain="poalimparents.bankhapoalim.co.il"; rbzns.ctrbg="FBJbOCP+Rehoy7Oy/WdwW78giok75ZJ41qiRAeMY6ngbkLDEoRQiaRnij/E1vDpJr8bXfF2RriK5XaIq/Hp55vlAaMCPBIVryBF/YYXoti09rQmZeDa16289c+L2T8eFOCCIjmmtSn7gp75lWrKDHxJgS7Te/RxMGL/93TjdGxpofgMceO/Z2y/d7oCYNO/HKn4ZciE4aqCU8AU6rtyVjH0HxWz47/pps9uqcV0VnR/up4gHLztME+GHfJzjZ80Vy/14g5wvCKRtZU7P6I3zgQ==";rbzns.rbzreqid="bnhp-rbzr0131343537323737333137e0b31050bf436236"; winsocks(true);</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm not trying to get the script tag inside the page.

**Why am I not getting all the other tags? How can I get this kind of pages?**

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some headers that your browser would send, too. Also a cookie might be required - you could fetch one with a "normal" browser.

Example (curl):

```
curl "http://poalimparents.bankhapoalim.co.il/" -H "Host: poalimparents.bankhapoalim.co.il" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" --compressed -H "DNT: 1" -H "Cookie: rbzreqid=bnhp-rbzr0231343537323737353630894b901088a07d30; rbzid=YnVIYjc0K2RmTDFXZFdiZy95UTNrOUJ0NEp0MzgzbW9oNlhHcFdVMU1mR25oT1NGQXowdGdZbjR3WktuQ2ZBZ0ljUTVCbHFDK213bGZXRk1DekJMMnhQMVFZVG4zcHpNT1lEWTRpM3FVeiswbkxtaFVCR25CU0taQ2pnNU1IQ1Z5WDc2ZWgxa2ZxR25vR1JadFpTVThidWs0d0s5QUF2YUVRSG1QcUpsS1ltRGpYNzhPR0lpRDNkak1VRmVxdm5nY0RpM1dEUnYrWU1rR2R1c3pWY2JGZHd6ODlOdkxHUkxuOW03N0VzWC9oOD1AQEAwQEBALTc0MDc0MDczNDA-" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "If-Modified-Since: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 11:40:18 GMT" -H "If-None-Match: W/""af3920fb581df1e4de68d46a4694689a""" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
```

Comment: You don't need to thank me - you already did by accepting the answer. Btw, this puzzled me actually and I had some fun fiddling it out :)